# Convert SVG vector to Android multi-density png drawables

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have some icons in SVG format, and want to convert them to Android png drawables, in the following sizes: `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi` and `drawable-xxxhdpi`.

What's the easiest way to convert an SVG to drawable pngs?

Comment: You don't need to convert SVG to PNG. You can directly use them in Android. With the latest support library, this will even work with old Android versions. See http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html.

Comment: @Codo I've heard that SVGs only work from API level 20 onwards, I was hoping to use API level 19 as my minimum. When you say 'old Android versions', how old is old?

Comment: The linked blog post says it: API level 7. If you need AnimatedVectorDrawable, it's API level 11.

Comment: @Codo, those aren't native SVG's, though. They're VectorDrawables converted from SVG's before compile-time. If you want to use actual SVG's at runtime, you can check out the [AndroidSVG library](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg) or even my [imageloader](https://github.com/mattsilber/imageloader) that directly integrates with it.

Comment: @Guardanis: You are referring to a feature introduced in Android Studio 1.4 where SVG where converted at build-time. But the support library doesn't do this anymore. It renders them at run-time. Read the linked blog post.

Comment: @Codo I can't find anything related to that at in the blog post you linked except for: "Vector drawables allow you to replace multiple png assets with a single vector graphic, defined in XML" and all of the information afterwards is about integrating the build VectorDrawables. There's no mention of direct SVG support anywhere, and I can't find any data supporting that via a quick google search. But I would REALLY, REALLY, REALLY love to be proved wrong here, though, so please share any resources you have!

Comment: @Codo `SVGs != VectorDrawables`. VectorDrawables use a very limited subset of the SVG directives.

Comment: @Guardanis there are FREE libraries to load SVGs (they convert them on the fly to a Bitmap). Search for `android-svg` and `svg-android`. But there are also some others. Some can handle compressed SVGs as well.

Comment: Thanks for that info @Rotwang but I'm already aware of those, and have actually integrated the AndroidSVG library directly into my [imageloader](https://github.com/mattsilber/imageloader) that actually supports loading SVGs over the net instead of just locally. I was just really hoping Codo was onto something in the support libraries that I wasn't aware of :(

Comment: I guess we ALL hoped in a Google direct support for REAL SVG files. Then we got the VectorDrawable DELUSION... ;)

Comment: I don't know where you use PNG images in Android. I almost exclusively use them in `ImageView`s. For that purpose, SVGs can now be used. Use the Support Library 23 or higher write `<ImageView ... app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon" />` instead of  `<ImageView ... src="@drawable/ic_icon" />`. It's a subset of SVG but it mostly works.

Comment: It's 2023 yet you still need a set of PNGs to customize RatingBar. It can't work with Vector Drawables. This behavior was marked "AsIntended" by the GoogleTeam in their issue tracker. Lol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Question might be a bit outdated, but I searched Internet and didn't find any good solution. So I wrote a simple bash script which does conversion of SVG as well as raster image formats.

Here it is:
https://gist.github.com/tntclaus/18f4fe7e8540f1cb283d2c7d8ad21d69

Usage:

`./generateAndroidDrawables.sh <image.file> <dp>`

It requires at least ImageMagic, which on OS X can be installed via `brew` or `macports`. Unfortunately ImageMagic poorly converts SVG, so I added support of Inkscape. If Inkscape is not installed, script falls back to ImageMagic conversion.

Comment: In order to optimize your apk / app bundle size, shouldn't you prefer SVG over PNG or JPG?

Answer (score 7):

There is an online [tool](https://respresso.io/image-converter?so) I worked on which can convert an svg image to different platforms, including android.

By default it will convert it to Android drawable, so you need to change the Android setting from auto to png and it will create all the densities you need.

Please note that the mdpi resolution will have the same size as the svg. So you may need to change the width/height parameters to enlarge to output. Or your can try the service for free which will let you specify the output resolution of the mdpi version.

Answer (score 2):

This is too late but I found this [Github Java project, named SVG to PNG Converter,](https://github.com/sterlp/svg2png) really quick and easy to convert SVG files to Android compatible png drawables.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this recently, I saw answers but they are difficult.

This online [tool](https://appicon.co/) too much easier https://appicon.co/

You can convert any image to android multi density or IOS